# SQL isn't echo'ing the array?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I really can't work out why this isn't displaying and value in the echo:

```
      $SQL = "
SELECT b.tagId
     , a.tagTitle
     , COUNT(b.tagId) AS value
  FROM itemTags b
  LEFT 
  JOIN tags a 
    ON a.iD = b.tagId
 GROUP 
    BY b.tagId
 ORDER 
    BY value DESC
 LIMIT 5";
                      $exeSQL=mysqli_query($conn, $SQL) or die (mysqli_error());
                      while ($arrayq=mysqli_fetch_array($exeSQL))
                      {
                        echo "<a href=''>".$arrayq['a.tagTitle']."</a>";              
                      }
```

It will only output the amount of anchors I am expecting but they are empty and i'm really struggling to work out what I have done wrong?

Comment: What is the error message saying?

Comment: Try `$arrayq['tagTitle']` instead of `a.tagTitle`. The table aliases usually aren't passed back in the keys

Comment: Is your query running on its own directly in database ?

Comment: I get "Undefined index: a.tagTitle". I've run just the SQL by itself and the query returns as expected

Comment: Note that, in general, if a non-aggregated column appears in the SELECT, then it should also appear in the GROUP BY. And it's `tagtitle`, not `a.tagtitle`

Comment: @aynber that was the issue! I'm sure i've "a." etc. before and just assumed i'd need to reference the table

Comment: I think you should get `$arrayq['tagTitle']` and not `$arrayq['a.tagTitle']`